# Multi-dimensional Itô-isometry

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am looking to prove the following equation: $$\left(\int_s^t \sigma(X_r)dW_r\right)\left(\int_s^t \sigma(X_r)dW_r\right)^\top = \int_s^t \sigma(X_r)\sigma(X_r)^\top dr$$

for a function $\sigma(x)\in R^{d\times d}$ that is continuous and $W$ a d-dimensional Wiener process.
I am not even sure if this is true, but it would suffice if these two terms were relatively close to each other. Since in the case that $d=1$, this is just the Itô-formula, I suspect this to be true.

I tried applying the multi-dimensional Itô-formula but this did not yield anything useful.

I am thankful for any hints.

Comment: Hint: in index notation, you're claiming$$\int_{[s,\,t]^2}\sigma_i(X_p)\sigma_j(X_q)dW_pdW_q=\int_s^t\sigma_i(X_r)\sigma_j(X_r)dr,$$so you just need [the inner product version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry).

Comment: I think you mean those are equal in expectation, not actually equal.